# Is $\ln (x/y) = \ln |x| - \ln |y|$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If I am to find the $y$ of the following equation

$$\ln(x/y) = x + y,$$

you would first try to split the left-hand side by doing $\ln x - \ln y$.

My question is, do you need to put the absolute function over both $x$ and $y$?

I think although you know that $x/y > 0$, you don't know if both are bigger or smaller than zero. In my opinion I don't think it's mathematically correct since both $x$ and $y$ could be negative. So I'm wondering if it's more correct to write like this instead:

$$\ln |x| - \ln |y| = x + y.$$

Could anyone let me know if this is indeed the correct way to split the log? Thanks!

Comment: One approach would be to treat the cases $x <0,y<0$ and $x>0,y>0$ seperately

Comment: You need not be concerned about the signs if you're differentiating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression $\ln(x/y)$ only makes sense when $x/y>0$. In this specific case we have, $x>0$ and $y>0$, or, $x<0$ and $y<0$. When ($x>0$ and $y>0$) or ($x<0$ and $y<0$), we can write,

$$\frac xy=\frac{|x|}{|y|}$$
and then,

$$\ln (x/y)=\ln |x|-\ln |y|.$$

Comment: In this case $x/y<0$ and $\ln (x/y)$ is not a real number

Comment: Of course but your identity is not a correct one.

Comment: @user, my identity is valid when $x/y>0$. Which is the case I am analysing and it is the case in the OP's problem

Comment: @user: what is so difficult to understand. What I am saying is that my identity is valid when, $x/y>0$, which is the case for this specific problem

Comment: You are saying “ in both case...” and I can’t see the asker is referring only to this case.

Comment: @user: Take another look at the statement. OP says that $x/y>0$

Comment: Are you referring to “ I think although you know that $x/y > 0$...”?

Comment: ok now I got what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

We need $\frac x y>0$ then within this case to split the $\log$ the expression $\ln(x/y)=\ln |x| - \ln |y| = x + y$ is fine.

As an alternative we can consider directly the two cases

- $x,y>0$

$$\ln\left(\frac xy\right) = x + y \iff \ln x - \ln y=x+y $$

- $x,y<0$

$$\ln\left(\frac {-x}{-y}\right) = x + y \iff \ln (-x) - \ln (-y)=x+y$$

More effectively, to isolate $y$, let take exponential both side to obtain

$$\ln\left(\frac xy\right) = x + y \iff \frac x y=e^xe^y\iff ye^y =xe^{-x} $$

that is

$$y=W(xe^{-x})$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: And none of this is needed for differentiating.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola I've given an advice to split the original equation in two parts. I wasn't considering the needing. Are you sure it is to take derivative? Thanks

Comment: @MarkViola It seems the aim is to isolate $y$.

Comment: The original title and body of the question seems to have changed.  I've given a (+1) to neutralize one of the nefarious downvoters.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks a lot Mark, your kindness and appreciation neutralize and cancel out any kind of nefarious behavior! Regards

Answer (score 1):

In itself, $\ln |x| - \ln |y| = x + y$ will produce spurious solutions of the form $x=-y$.

An alternative approach could be to solve $\ln x - \ln y = x + y$ when $x>0$ and $y>0$

and then note that any positive solution $x=a,y=b$ which satisfies that also produces the negative solution $x=-b,y=-a$

The positive solutions are not simple, but using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) you have $$y=W\left(x e^{-x}\right).$$  With the reflection for the negative solutions you get an answer like this in red, with a discontinuity at $(0,0)$; the extreme values on top and to the left are about $(1, 0.2784645)$  and its reflection $(-0.2784645,-1)$

[image]

Comment: @user : if $(x_p,y_p)$ is a positive solution then $\ln (x_p / y_p)=x_p+y_p$ so letting $x_n=-y_p,y_n=-x_p$ you have $\ln (x_n / y_n) = \ln (y_p / x_p) = - \ln (x_p / y_p)=-x_p-y_p =y_n+x_n=x_n+y_n$ so $(x_n,y_n)=(-y_p,-x_p)$ is a negative solution

Comment: Yes of course now it is clear to me. Thanks